# How can I know the SHA type in OpenSSL ChaCha cipher

Tags: security, ssl, encryption, openssl, pyopenssl

I want to check `OpenSSL 1.1.0g` against an application ciphersuite lists. The application I have has ciphersuites as follows:
ecdhe-ecdsa-chacha20-poly1305-sha256
ecdhe-rsa-chacha20-poly1305-sha256

By checking Openssl TLS 1.2 ciphers using the command: `openssl ciphers -s -tls1_2 -V` I got some ChaCha ciphersuites as follows:

```
0xCC,0xA9 - ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD

0xCC,0xA8 - ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
```

The only difference is that OpenSSL ciphersuite name does not contain the SHA type. There are many SHA types (256, 384, etc.). How can I know what is the SHA type in OpenSSL ciphersuites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`openssl ciphers` shows you the codes for this ciphers, i.e. `0xCC,0xA9` and `0xCC,0xA8`. According to [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4) these codes map to `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256` and `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256` which are both defined in [RFC 7905](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7905).